# sort data in one column by grouping in another column

Tags: r, excel

I have a Data frame is like:

```
account  data
a        10
b        20
c        30
a        40
b        50
c        60
a        70
```

output:

```
#account  data
#a        10
#a        40
#a        70
#b        20
#b        50
#c        30
#c        60
```

I have tried with `group_by` and `arrange`, but not it is working

Comment: What is exactly not working? Try `arrange(df, account, data)`

Comment: I don't think you need `group_by` here. What you're doing is sorting by firstly account, and then data.

Comment: it worked .Thanks..u r right.no group by here